# Change output directory for maven2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-2

I am creating my first maven2 project and i cant find anything on this by googling.

Can you tell me how to change the default output directory away from "target"
I want to be able to name the directory myself.

when i change the build paths for the project and modules in intellij settings, the target folder is still created - although empty. 
I want it gone for good please :)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `file / settings / build. Execution, Deployment / Compiler` there is a point `AnnotationProcessors` this is where the `target` folder was being created from.
By turning this off, since i wasnt using it, i got the wanted output when building.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing maven via command line, you can add following profile in your pom.xml file:

```
    <profile>
        <id>customOutput</id>
        <build>
            <directory>/your/directory/path/</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

and can then execute

```
mvn compile -PcustomOutput
```

If you want Intellij Idea to handle, you can do by:

> File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Paths

Select `Use module compile output path`:

Then input the custom paths.

Comment: I tried both, couldnt get i t to work. See my own answer if you want to know how i fixed it :)